# Need to access data in JSON.stringify object

Tags: javascript, json, onclick, google-visualization

The background for this question is I'm trying to access the selected cell from addListener in google visualization calendar. I could print the selected cell using `JSON.stringify(chart.getSelection());`. It prints as `[{"date":1468195200000,"row":0}]`.

**My problem** is to access this date object. I tried to access it as

```
var obj=JSON.stringify(chart.getSelection());
        console.log('selected value '+obj.date);
```

But it displays as `Undefined`. When I print the `obj` it displays as [object, object]

If you need more information please let me know. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: there is a typo , it will be JSON.stringify but not SON.stringify

Comment: If you need to read the content of the data, why are you converting it to a string representation?

Comment: @user2181397 thanks, I corrected.

Comment: @squnint I tried var obj=chart.getSelection();
  console.log('selected value '+obj.date);
  But sitll undefined.

Answer (score 9):

JSON.stringify() serializes a data object into a string. Just access the object directly.

```
var data = chart.getSelection()[0]; // assuming there is only ever one item in the selection array.
console.log(data.date)
```

Comment: `data` is an array, you have to access the correct array element first then the property

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```js
var data = [{"date":1468195200000,"row":0}]

var rw = data[0].row;
var dt = new Date(data[0].date);

console.log(rw);
console.log(dt);
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans: what are you talkin about? I've give him the sample with the right portions, so she/he can learn and doing by self. He/she need to solve the problem, not "WHY"? if he/she say "WHY", I'll give the explanation. SO, why you doesn't teach him? not giving any answer, just complaining other people answers...

Answer (score 1):

**careful** when accessing the first array element directly when listening for the `'select'` event

`chart.getSelection()[0]`

the `'select'` event is fired, both when a selection is made, AND removed

so **the above line will fail** when the selection is removed

check the `length` before accessing...

```
  selection = chart.getSelection();
  // check selection length
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    console.log(selection[0].date);
  } else {
    console.log('selection removed');
  }
```

see following working snippet, select a date, then select again to remove the selection...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id :'Score' });
    dataTable.addRows([
      [ new Date(2016, 3, 13), 101 ],
      [ new Date(2016, 3, 14), 102 ],
      [ new Date(2016, 3, 15), 103 ],
      [ new Date(2016, 3, 16), 104 ],
      [ new Date(2016, 3, 17), 105 ]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
      var selection = chart.getSelection();

      // check selection length
      if (selection.length > 0) {
        console.log(selection[0].date);
      } else {
        console.log('selection removed');
      }
    });
    chart.draw(dataTable);
  },
  packages:["calendar"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: the Calendar chart can never have more than one selected date, hope this helps...

Comment: need to check `length` before accessing `[0]`, or error will be thrown when not selected...

Answer (score 0):

This is an array of objects however there is only one object in this array (or so I think) so what you should do is `console.log(obj[0].date);` instead!